# How to run Emacs under Wine?

Tags: microsoft-windows

I need to debug some issues which my configuration has while running on Windows

Is it possible to run Emacs binary [1] under Wine for that?

The installer works fine, but `runemacs.exe` fails with this error

```
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 00010000-00110000
Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specifie
d file.
ShellExecuteEx failed: Bad EXE format for C:\Program Files\Emacs\emacs-29.1\bin\
runemacs.exe.
```

1: https://gnu.mirror.constant.com/emacs/windows/emacs-29/emacs-29.1_1-installer.exe

Comment: Just tested, works for me. Please add to your post details: what distro are you using; and please list wine-related packages. So e.g. on fedora `rpm -qa | grep wine`, on Ubuntu'n'co `dpkg -l | grep wine`.

Comment: But as something for you to look into: most likely you have only installed 32-bit version of wine but not x64. You need to install both.

Answer (score 0):

I tested and Emacs works fine for me under WINE. The error you're posting is typically a result of running a 64-bit only WINE. So the answer is to install a WINE that supports both 32 and 64 bit applications.

Unfortunately the author still didn't provide the information about the distro they is running, so it's impossible to tell what package exactly they need to enable 32-bit support.

For Ubuntu the correct installation instructions [are here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) *(the instructions use a 3rd-party repository because Ubuntu typically have most packages outdated, including WINE. That's part of their policy)*.

For Fedora instructions can be found [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Fedora). It's also a 3rd-party repo, though you may be just fine using the one from the Fedora repository. It sometimes may be somewhat outdated, but not by as much as Ubuntu one, just by one or two versions.

Those are official docs from winehq, which should get you running both 32 and 64 bit.